# Reduce the amount of trampolines type 2 used

Tags: trampolines

we are developing a iOS app using Unity3D and we have run into the "Ran out of trampolines type 2 error" all the time. Since Unity doesn't allow use to adjust the trampoline limit, so we have to reduce the amount of trampoline used. So far, we have donea few things like removing some LINQ calls and seems to have improved the situation a bit. But in reality we are still not really sure  if the things we are doing is helping or not.

So i'm wondering if someone can tell us what exactly is trampolines type 2 and how can we reduce the amount of trampolines type 2 sued by our app? thanks!

Thanks!

This is my original question back few weeks ago:
[MonoDevelop settings to fix "ran out of trampolines type 2" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591128/monodevelop-settings-to-fix-ran-out-of-trampolines-type-2-error)